# Git checkout first time versus subsequent uses

Tags: git, git-checkout

So, i am at my master branch working.

I issue :

```
git checkout -b branch1
```

This will create a new branch named branch1 and will make it identical to my current branch master.

Git does this "mirroring" only the first time that i run it?

Every subsequent call to git checkout will just fetch the data for the branch i checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.

When you create a new branch it is initially identical to the branch it was made from.  However, once that branch has been created any calls to `checkout` work only against that branch.  Other tools, such as `merge` are used to work with your new branch against any other branch.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't have to fetch the data when you checkout a new branch, it already has it and has to only change the view you see on disk. When you create a new branch, there's very little to do, since with or without the branch designation the data is there already. A branch is simply a pointer to that data; when the branch is modified its pointer is moved forward.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging is a good introduction to how it works.